# pip3 install spyder with AttributeError: '_NamespacePath'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, spyder

In Ubuntu 16.04, I would like to install `spyder3` on my default `python3` without installing Anaconda, but when I launch `pip3` and `spyder3`, I get this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip does not work after upgrade to ubuntu-16.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184792/pip-does-not-work-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10)

Answer (score 2):

This error comes from pip. Update pip and setuptools :

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then install spyder again with pip.

Source : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2990

Comment: pip3 does not work for me. Actually, when I type pip3 on the terminal, this error will appear.