# Unable to use pip3 to install packages

Tags: python, pip

Hey guys I think my pip3 has just hit a snag. Can somebody help me with this.
I ran this command:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

And it gave this as an output:
This output is not only with tensorflow package but with any package i try to install with pip3.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/het/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/het/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/home/het/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/het/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/het/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/home/het/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/home/het/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/het/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/home/het/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

What can be the reason
Edit: pip works just fine but pip3 doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip does not work after upgrade to ubuntu-16.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184792/pip-does-not-work-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10)

Comment: No i tried that. But it still doesn't work

Comment: Try my answer @HetShah

Comment: but won't pip install tensorflow add the package to python2 and i use python3.

Answer (score 0):

Try update pip and setuptools

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Also, the best way is using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar Why?!

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong syntax. Just try `pip install tensorflow` in command prompt and everything should run smoothly. I tried at my end and it worked. Refer attached image. See the first few lines and the last few lines.[image]