# Python3-pip3 : AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, attributeerror

Please bear with me as this question comes again.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 I tried to install Kmodes with pip3 but I get this error. I tried removing pip/pip3 from scratch and re-install it didn't solve the problem.

I found previous questions about the same issue but It didn't address it like `pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools`.

What is the solution to this problem and what can I do to solve it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/stambouli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/stambouli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/home/stambouli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/stambouli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/stambouli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/home/stambouli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/home/stambouli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/stambouli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/home/stambouli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots, please. Edit the question and add the error as text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip does not work after upgrade to ubuntu-16.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184792/pip-does-not-work-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10)

Answer (score 2):

Change the line in pkg_resources/_init_.py (in my case this was in `~/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/`):

```
orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
```

to

```
orig_path = sorted(orig_path, key=position_in_sys_path)
```