# ipython giving attributeerror when launched

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pip, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I launch

```
ipython
```

I get

```
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I can do nothing. I tried to pip3 uninstall stuff but I get the same message (the stack of the error being slightly different). Waht I can do? Should I burn the computer and restart with a new one? python works fine.

Full stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 16, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 91, in <module>
    class TerminalInteractiveShell(InteractiveShell):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 134, in TerminalInteractiveShell
    highlighting: \n %s""" % ', '.join(get_all_styles())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygments/styles/__init__.py", line 79, in get_all_styles
    for name, _ in find_plugin_styles():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygments/plugin.py", line 62, in find_plugin_styles
    for entrypoint in iter_entry_points(STYLE_ENTRY_POINT):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygments/plugin.py", line 45, in iter_entry_points
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: Did you try to install to install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/what-is-anaconda/) ? it works fine with it. You might be missing a dependencie. Did you install like `pip install ipython` ?

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: [@jww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww) I don't tink there is any code to show unfortunately, it's more that he wants to start ipython from the terminal, from what I can guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip does not work after upgrade to ubuntu-16.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184792/pip-does-not-work-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your version of python (assuming you're on v3.x), or a missed dependencie.

Try to uninstall ipython

```
pip uninstall ipython
```

Then upgrade your pip and setuptool version (they might not be up to date causing problems):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Run the installation of ipython again either with:

- with `pip`

```sh
pip install ipython
```

- or `easy_install`:

```sh
easy_install ipython
```

- or from the source using other procedures in the iptyhon [installation doc](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/install.html).

On my side I often use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) which has most dependencies and package already integrated and working. So you may try it out if the above does not work for you.

Comment: pip uninstall ipython: 
"Cannot uninstall requirement ipython, not installed"

Comment: Oh then skip this part and continue (upgrading then try to reinstall again) let me know if that works ;)