# error occurred when 'pip install google-cloud-speech'

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-speech

Thanks for reading.

I do need your help.

I wanted to install google-cloud-speech, so I typed

'pip install google-cloud-speech'

in cmd.exe(Windows 10)

but error occured.

Is there any proper way to solve this, please let me know it.

Thanks.

```
Collecting google-cloud-speech
  Using cached google_cloud_speech-0.32.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests<3.0dev,>=2.18.4 (from google-cloud-speech)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting googleapis-common-protos[grpc]<2.0dev,>=1.5.2 (from google-cloud-speech)
  Using cached googleapis-common-protos-1.5.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\developer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, filterfalse, map
      File "c:\users\developer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extern\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
      File "c:\users\developer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3017, in <module>
        @_call_aside
      File "c:\users\developer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\developer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3045, in _initialize_master_working_set
        dist.activate(replace=False)
      File "c:\users\developer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2577, in activate
        declare_namespace(pkg)
      File "c:\users\developer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2151, in declare_namespace
        _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
      File "c:\users\developer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2091, in _handle_ns
        _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
      File "c:\users\developer\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2120, in _rebuild_mod_path
        orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
    AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-91vxtz3t\googleapis-common-protos\
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip does not work after upgrade to ubuntu-16.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184792/pip-does-not-work-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10)

Comment: From your stack trace it seems that you are using python 3.6. Can you try running with pip3 instead of pip?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you and found a solution [on the Google Platform Git](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2990).

In my case, it was because pip was not up-to-date. Just do :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install google-cloud
```